# Bind list of DataTables to RowDetailsTemplate of datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datatable

I am developing wpf application based on MVVM software architecture pattern.
I have a main `DataTable` which I am directly binding to DataGrid. I have a list of DataTables, I want to display them whenever a row is of `DataGrid` is clicked. The code below is a sample code just to understand how it is done. My actual projects follows MVVM in which I will be applying this concept.

```
<Window x:Class="HierDataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Nested">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TableCollection}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TableCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource Nested}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CS File

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public List<DataTable> TableCollection { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TableCollection = new List<DataTable>();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
            TableCollection.Add(table);
            TableCollection.Add(table);
            TableCollection.Add(table);
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
```

I am able to directly bind the list to data grid but not as a template of RowDetailsTemplate in datagrid, when the row is clicked there is nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, After trying a bit, I am able to solve it. The problem was with binding in DataTemplat

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Nested">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=TableCollection}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: great find! you may accept the answer and let others know that this can solve the mentioned issue.